# Rename tags with truncated names for locked posts

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

When the tag character limit was increased recently, [I asked](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/should-we-get-the-increase-in-the-tag-length-limit#comment8263_4060) if we should flag questions with tags that could now be better names and was given a green light. This works well for the vast majority of questions, but I've noticed a number of locked identification requests that I can't flag, [since they are historically locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193365/261498):

- [in-clothes-called-fat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-clothes-called-fat): the localised title is *In the Clothes Called Fat*.
- [bocchi-bokura-renai-jijou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bocchi-bokura-renai-jijou): full title is *Bocchi na Bokura no Renai Jijou*.
- [jeanie-light-brown-hair](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jeanie-light-brown-hair): full title is *Jeanie with the Light Brown Hair*

There may be some others; these were the most obvious ones to me when I was looking at my own tags and the list of those that had been created with the retagging effort.

Comment: Updated all of these - thanks! If you see any other historical-locked ones that should be updated, please do make additional posts on meta.